# Show this number always is composite number

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

**Conjecture:**

> Let $m$ be a positive integer. Then
>   $$f(m)=(2m)^{2m+1}+m^{2m+1}\cdot (2m+1)^m+(2m+1)^{2m}$$
>   is not a prime number.

One can prove it when $m$ is odd number, it is clear that $f(m)$ is an even number in this case.

But for $m$ even, it is not easy to show the conjecture. See some example values:
$$f(2) = 4^5 + 2^5 \cdot 5^2 + 5^4 = 2449 = 31\cdot 79$$
$$f(4) = 8^9 + 4^9 \cdot 9^4 + 9^8 = 1897191233 = 7\cdot 53\cdot 73\cdot 70051$$
$$f(6) = 12^{13} + 6^{13} \cdot 13^6 + 13^{12} = 63171766713176497 = 281\cdot 2003681\cdot 112198777$$

Using Maple, one can verify the conjecture for even $m≤1300$.

For $m=1008$, the answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771649/show-this-number-maybe-is-prime/2771684#2771684) contains a proof, because using Fermat's little theorem it shows $f(1008)\equiv 5 \pmod 5$.

Can we show a factorization, that is, can we look for $g(m),h(m)\in Z[x]$, such that $$f(m)=g(m)\cdot h(m)?$$

Comment: What is the motivation for this question?

Comment: I just find this form very interesting, and if this conjecture is correct, that is, the value of this formula just avoids the prime number situation, which is very convincing.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris, I think it's a straightforward generalisation of the linked question.

Comment: Crossposted at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771998/show-this-number-always-is-composite-number).

Comment: Maybe it comes from the fact that the associated function of two variables  $ f^{*}(a,b ; g)=(g(a))^{b} +a^{b}.b^{a}+b^{g(a)} $ is invariant under permutation of the variables  $ g(a) $ and  $ b $ on one hand outside the product and under permutation of  $ a $ and  $ b $ on the other hand in the product. When you think of a prime as a number of objects that can't be arranged as a rectangle, it seems to indicate that in some sense primes have no non-trivial symmetry. Ideas from Galois theory might help solve this intriguing question.

Comment: It's impossible for there to be a factorization $f(m)=g(m)h(m)$ where $g,h\in\Bbb Z[x]$, because $f(m)$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: If $m \equiv 8$ mod $20$ then $f(m)$ is divisible by 5. Similarly if $m \equiv 4,16,22,30$ mod $42$ then $f(m)$ is divisible by 7. One can find other examples by noticing that if $p$ is prime then $f(m)$ mod $p$ depends only on $m$ mod $p(p-1)$ by Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: If we use the heuristics that a number $n$ is prime with probability $1 / \log n$, the expected number of $m \le x$ with $f(m)$ prime is $\sim \log \log x$. I don't think checking for $m \le 1300$ is good enough support.